# Group actions on topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

There  exists  a connected topological  space  such  that the  permutations  group $S_3$ acting without  fixed  points?  I  try  to  consider  matrice spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a trivial example, you can take $S_3$ itself with the indiscrete topology, with the group acting by translation.

Assuming you want a less trivial example (say, something like a nice subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$), here's a hint on how to find one.  Notice that $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^3$ by permuting the coordinates.  Unfortunately, this action has some fixed points, so it doesn't quite work.  But if you remove all the points of $\mathbb{C}^3$ which are fixed by a non-identity element of $S_3$, can you prove that the resulting space is still connected?

(As an extra exercise, you can try and see why this wouldn't work for $\mathbb{R}^3$: if you remove the fixed points of non-identity elements, you are left with a disconnected space.)

Comment: Why   $R^3$   is   not  good?   If   we   want  that   the    action  to   be   fixed   point  free    we  must  to   consider   $R^3$   without  the   line   generated by (1,1,1).  This   space is  connected, no?

Comment: Acctualy   my  definition  for  fixed  point   was    wrong.  Now   I  see  why  $R^3$  is  not   good.   We   must  to get   out  an  hyperplane so   what  remain  is  not  conncted.